# how to restrict user from accessing pages which is not issued by admin to user in laravel5.2?

Tags: laravel-5

user login is provided in my work.Admin creates user and assign roles for the user.When user login to his page by using username and password,the user is allowed to access only the pages issued by the admin.But the problem in my work is that when a user login to his page can access pages which is not issued by admin by using URL of the page.How can i restrict the user from accessing page using URL

Comment: Show us how you implemented the restriction and what you've already done

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the url by mentioning the permission in route level.

It can be achieved by using the package "bican roles" which is meant for  roles and permission.

If you want, refer this link

https://github.com/romanbican/roles